# How to return column value of that string value when given as input

Tags: r

I have a below data frame for which I must search the string values and return the other columns 
It should return values depending on the input I give

```
Ex : 
Enter the number you want to search
Input 1 = 14
Inout 2 = 16
```

Combining above two, I have `14,16` as a string, then it should return me the below

```
rhs        name 
15          salt
```

Below is the Dataframe where we can search our inputs(it should search only on lhs )

DF:

```
lhs         rhs              name
32,39,6     65          jackfruit
39,6,65     32          coffee
14,16,26    15         salts
16,20,4     26           marshmallows
16,26,33    4            veggies
53          31           candy
```

This search should accept for any number of strings and should be able to search.
For suppose, my input is `14,16,26` it should return the value

```
rhs name
15  salt
```

Also, if its only 16, then it should return

```
Rhs      name
15        salts 
26        marshmallows 
4           veggies.
```

I have tried using the below code but it just uses the order for example:

CODE:

```
df[grep('16,20', df$lhs),]
```

output :

```
rhs   name
    26    marshmallows
```

But if change my search like below,

CODE:

```
df[grep('16,4', df$lhs),] (#leaving the number 20 )
```

the above one gives me an error.

Expected output :

```
 rhs   name
    26    marshmallows
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Don't work with CSV data like this.  Instead, get your range spread out over rows and columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you model the range as a starting and ending value, each in its own column, it will probably be easier to work with than a CSV list.

Comment: @Sotos Can you  help me out now, I think you should be having an idea  now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
df <- read.table(text = "lhs         rhs              name
32,39,6     65          jackfruit
39,6,65     32          coffee
14,16,26    15         salts
16,20,4     26           marshmallows
16,26,33    4            veggies
53          31           candy    ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

# define input values:
input1 <- 14
input2 <- 16

library(dplyr)

# create a data frame in long format for search:
search_df <- unnest(mutate(df, lhs = strsplit(x = lhs, split = "\\D+")))

# now search for names where all inputs are in lhs:
search_df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(all(c(input1, input2) %in% lhs)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(rhs, name)
```

**Edit:**
If you want more flexibility regarding inputs, just go for one:

```
input <- c(14, 16)
search_df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(all(input %in% lhs)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(rhs, name)
```

Comment: what if I dont enter any value for `input 2` ? and my `input 1` is still 14, it should return me  the one which contains only 14 ...can we get that ?

Comment: @pylearner maybe it is better to use just one input but give it more than one value, for example `input <- c(14)` or `input <- c(14, 16)` . Otherwise, just set `input2 <- NULL`. But my advise would be to go for the single-input-approach.

Comment: Thanks Tino, Also look at my solution  .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rje)
myfun <- function(input){
    result <- apply(rules, 1, function(x){is.subset(input, as.vector(unlist(strsplit(x[2], ','))))})
    result <- rules[result, ]

    return (result)
}
```